# Help me to crete graph in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

Here i have created a grid.But when large number of columns comes flash quit unexpectedly.

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.Strong;

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import fl.motion.Color;
    import flash.text.TextField;



    public class Line extends MovieClip
    {



        public function Line()
        {


            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,createGraphContainer);


            // constructor code
        }
        public function createGraphContainer(ev:Event):void
        {
            var grid:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            var numColumns:Number = 50;
            var numRows:Number = 25;
            var cellHeight:Number = 5;
            var cellWidth:Number = 10;

            grid.graphics.clear();
            grid.graphics.lineStyle(.5, 0xFFECDB);

            // we drop in the " + 1 " so that it will cap the right and bottom sides.;
            for (var col:Number = 0; col < numColumns + 1; col++)
            {
                for (var row:Number = 0; row < numRows + 1; row++)
                {
                    addChild(grid);
                    grid.x = 50;
                    grid.y = 50;
                    //trace(col, row);
                    grid.graphics.moveTo(0, row * cellHeight);
                    grid.graphics.lineTo(cellWidth * numColumns, row * cellHeight);
                    grid.graphics.moveTo(col * cellWidth, 0);
                    grid.graphics.lineTo(col * cellWidth, cellHeight * numRows);


                }


            }

        }
    }

}
```

Here var numColumns:Number = 150;var numRows:Number = 225; flash quits unexpectedly.Give me a solution guys.

Comment: Does it run fine with a lower number of cols/rows?

Comment: @jackson yes.It works fine with lower nmber.

Comment: You need to display only visible items, plus 1-2 hidden on each end, like all Flex lists do. Make each row render into Sprite and move those sprites as datagrid scrolls. Reuse sprites to avoid garbage. Or just google for **actionscript datagrid**.

Comment: @alxx actually i want to create graph.not data grid.so.

Comment: Ok, I see... `addChild(grid);` - don't create too many children, draw what you need on parent's graphics directly. This will work much faster. Also, no need to use MovieClip where Sprite will do.

Comment: Or rather, you could create one sprite, draw the entire graph onto it, and add it (once) as a child. Also, you should only redraw the graph when it changes - ENTER_FRAME is probably overkill.

Comment: @Akhil I don't mind you using the code I posted but please go and accept the answers to your questions. As for this problem you are trying to build a grid that is way to big that is 33750 cells. Just make your grid a little bigger than the stage and work from that.

Answer (score 3):

you're adding row * col children ( in the nested loop: addchild( grid ) ) so you end up with a pile of row  * col movieclips containing increasingly complex vector drawings.
not good especially as this is done on enterframe !

actually it is a grid and should be drawn once, the graph itself would be drawn on antoher layer. you could pass the displayobject to a function if you have to redraw the grid.

plus you don't need nested loops : using a drawRect instead will give you the possibility of splitting the nested loops and as a rect draws the top and the bottom at once, you can event increment the loops by 2.

here's an example that should run slightly faster :)

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

public class Line extends MovieClip
{
    private var grid:Shape;
    public function Line()
    {
        //adds the canvas once
        grid = new Shape();
        grid.x = 50;
        grid.y = 50;
        addChild( grid );

        //draws once
        createGraphContainer( grid, 100, 25, 5, 2 );

        //draws in a loop
        //addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, redrawGrid );

    }

    private function redrawGrid(e:Event):void 
    {
        var t:uint = getTimer();
        var cols:int = 1 + int( Math.random() * 200 );
        var rows:int = 1 + int( Math.random() * 200 );
        var width:int = 1 + Math.random() * 10;
        var height:int = 1 + Math.random() * 10;
        createGraphContainer( grid, cols, rows, width, height );
        trace( 'redrawing took :', ( getTimer() - t ), 'for col:', cols, 'rows:', rows, 'cell width:', width, 'cell height:', height );
    }

    public function createGraphContainer( grid:Shape, numColumns:int = 100, numRows:int = 100, cellWidth:Number = 10, cellHeight:Number = 5 ):void
    {

        grid.graphics.clear();
        grid.graphics.lineStyle( 0.5, 0xFFECDB);
        //grid.graphics.beginFill( 0xFF0000, .25 ); // uncomment for debug

        var gridWidth:Number = numColumns * cellWidth;
        var gridHeight:Number = numRows * cellHeight;

        grid.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, gridWidth, gridHeight );

        for (var col:Number = 0; col < numColumns; col += 2 )
        {
            grid.graphics.drawRect( col * cellWidth, 0, cellWidth, gridHeight );
        }           
        for (var row:Number = 0; row < numRows; row += 2 )
        {
            grid.graphics.drawRect(  0, row * cellHeight, gridWidth, cellHeight );
        }

        grid.cacheAsBitmap = true;//not to be used in a loop very efficient if drawn once.
    }
}
}
```